# Why my code with OpenMP performance different on different environment?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I'm a newcomer to use OpenMP. These days I optimized a program and got different results on different environment. The kernel of my code looks like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int thread_id = 0; thread_id < max_thread; thread_id++)
{
    int work_start_pos = spos[thread_id];
    int work_end_pos = spos[thread_id + 1];
    for (int pos = work_start_pos; pos < work_end_pos; pos++)
    {
        //Calculate some parameters 
        //A loop with constant length to finish a convolve
    }
}
```

I compiled and tested it in different environments, the answers are right but the time used by the program are different:

All programs were compiled with : `-O2 -march=native -fopenmp`

```
    Windows 7 x64, MinGW GCC 4.7.1 64-bit, 
Xeon E3 1230v2 4 Core / 8 Threads @ 3.5GHz (I locked it when testing), 
8G DDR3 Mem @ 1600MHz
    1 Thread , 252.23s
    2 Threads, 126.44s
    4 Threads,  66.24s
    6 Threads,  65.56s
    8 Threads,  63.12s
```

Clearly it is linear speedup from 1 thread to 4 thread.

```
    Windows 8.1 x64, MinGW GCC 4.9.2 64-bit, 
i7 4702 MQ 4 Cores / 8 Threads, 8G DDR3L Mem @ 1600MHz. 
When only one CPU is fully loaded, it comes to 3.1GHz. When 4 CPUs are fully loaded, it various from 2.6GHz to 2.8GHz.

    1 Thread , 289.33s
    2 Threads, 161.56s
    4 Threads, 110.43s
    6 Threads, 109.89s
    8 Threads, 132.00s
```

It is not totally linear speedup, but nearly linear speedup. I guess maybe the CPU Boost has an effort on it.

```
Arch Linux Kernel 3.1.7 x64, GCC 4.9.2 , hardware is same as Windows 8.1 :

1 Thread , 226.67s
2 Threads, 208.82s
4 Threads, 237.58s
6 Threads, 248.67s
8 Threads, 247.11s
```

Very strange results here.

The cluster in our lab :

```
CentOS 6.3 x64 release Kernel 2.6.32 GCC 4.4.6, 
Core2 Q8400 @ 2.66GHz max (usually the CPU is 2.0GHz), 4 Cores / 4 Threads, 4G DDR3 Mem @ 1066MHz

1 Thread , 463.51s
2 Threads, 394.96s
4 Threads, 372.48s
```

It did speedup, when using more threads, but far from linear speedup. And I also tried to use GCC 4.9.2 to compile and test on the cluster, but almost changed nothing.

Comment: When you thought you're running on, say, 4 threads, are you sure you actually were? this can be checked using the OpenMP run-time library. Also, your code is not the proper way to use OpenMP.

Comment: Let me guess: You are using `clock()` to time the program execution?

Comment: @HristoIliev The program has a `"Stopwatch" module` using `clock()` to time the program execution, but it's not major code so I care little about it. Any suggestion?

Comment: That's a very common that mistake people make. `clock()` works differently on Windows than on most Unix-like systems. On Windows it returns the real (wall-clock) time passed since some point in the past while on Linux (also OS X, FreeBSD, etc.) it returns the _total CPU time used by all process threads_. One should use instead the portable OpenMP timer routine `omp_get_wtime()`.

Comment: @HristoIliev Sorry... I made a mistake... They use `struct tms t; m_start = times(&t);` and 
`struct tms t; return (static_cast<double>(stop - m_start)) / (static_cast<double>(sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)));` to time the program. When compiling it on Windows, I can't find "sys/times.h" so I used `omp_get_wtime()` instead. And it works well on Linux beacuse sometimes I used my watch on my hand to time the program and got the same result.

Comment: How do you set the number of threads? By calling ``omp_set_num_threads `` or you use default value?

Comment: @NikolayKondratyev I use the default value. When testing, sometimes I set the `max_thread` manually in my code smaller than the return of `omp_get_max_threads()` , so it won't use all threads.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but too long for a comment. I just wand to point out that `omp parallel for` should really only be used to parallelise `for` loops with (typically) many more iterations than threads. In order to have each thread get exactly one chunk, simply use `omp parallel` as in

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
    int work_start_pos = spos[thread_id];
    int work_end_pos = spos[thread_id + 1];
    for (int pos = work_start_pos; pos < work_end_pos; pos++)
    {
        //Calculate some parameters 
        //A loop with constant length to finish a convolve
    }
}
```

I doubt that this will make much of a difference with your timings, though, but you should try.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your code this morning again and it made no difference. The original program looks like `for (int d_index = 0; d_index < WorkSampleSize; d_index ++ ) { Calculation and other }` and I have devided it into different unrelated blocks to give each thread to work.